# The correct way of announcement

Tags: vocabulary

What is the right phrase as an announcement for the practice of allowing students to enrol in a college or school?

1. Admission open
2. Admissions open
3. Open Admissions

It is a marketing purpose phrase, by the way, that we see in newspapers or billboards.

Comment: "Open Admissions" in the context of a college or university has a specific meaning, namely that there are no requirements for admission other than a high school diploma (or equivalent). If that's the meaning you're looking for, that's the correct phrase; otherwise, it is misleading.

Comment: No, the ad means, 'Now one can enroll on the course in this school/ college, etc.' In this case, which of the mentioned above is ok?

Comment: none, you would say "Admissions *now* open" or "Admissions open October 1st" or something like that.